# While want to make an instance of SIFTDetector: Get an Attempted to read or write protected memory exception Error

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to use sift algorithm to make the keypoints and descriptors in c# by using opencv library.

```
     fileAddress = dlg.FileName;
     cap = new Emgu.CV.Capture(dlg.FileName);
     cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 3945);
     imGray = cap.QueryGrayFrame();
     Emgu.CV.Features2D.SIFTDetector siftDet = new Emgu.CV.Features2D.SIFTDetector();
     siftDet.DetectKeyPoints(imGray);
     MessageBox.Show("test SIFT");
```

but when it go through the line **Emgu.CV.Features2D.SIFTDetector siftDet = new Emgu.CV.Features2D.SIFTDetector();**  I face the error:

[image]

and view detail is as following:

[image]

How could I solve this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The openCv that I was using was version 2.1, then I upgraded the opencv*.* and *.dll files to version 2.4. The problem solved.

I couldn't find any explanation for that, that would be awesome if anybody could even give me an intuitive answer.

For now if you face such problem regarding working with SIFT, try the latest version.